# Cannot find .a static library files after building boost with macports, I only have dylib

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, build, macports

Using Xcode 7.1...

Built using command `sudo port install boost +universal`

I am under the impression that if I want to distribute my software, .dylib files will be required for every user because dylib is a dynamic library, while .a will be statically linked and so it will be embedded in the final product. Is this true? If so, how do I get .a files?

I'm trying to make use of regex and filesystem libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a MacPorts variant "no_static" that is enabled by default. To build the static library for boost, use (assuming you still require a universal binary)

```
sudo port install boost +universal -no_static
```

I found this easily after doing

```
port info boost
port variants boost
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes you need .a files. Use brew instead.

`brew install boost --universal`